# UserUpdateInfo' isn't a type. UserUpdateInfo updateuser = UserUpdateInfo();

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am having error with "UserUpdateInfo". I have seen it is deprecated but I tried all solution available online but I cannot solve it. Can anyone please help me out?

```
signup() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState?.save();

      try {
        UserCredential user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);
        if (user != null) {
          UserUpdateInfo updateuser = UserUpdateInfo();
          updateuser.displayName = _name;
          user.updateProfile(updateuser);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to update displayName use `updateDisplayName()`

```dart
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.updateDisplayName(displayName);
```

You can find others method on like `updatePhotoURL()` from User.

More about [auth/flutter/manage-users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users)